# How does any app for taking photos in burst mode from camera work?

Tags: android

I have seen apps like Fast Burst Camera Lite taking burst shots without any lag (with a compromise in quality of photo, of course). I was just curious how these apps work. I saw a few websites over the Internet but no satisfactory answer. So, I just thought of posting it here for the sake of getting a good discussion. There are no right or wrong answers. I just want to discuss. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this . it wll greatfull if you will help me..

Comment: @ArslanAhmad did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I observed is that this app "Fast Camera Lite" didn't lag. It might be using a multiple thread. One thread to just capture the images while another to save it. To reduce the lag, the app could just possibly have the first thread to capture image and dump the image data in a queue while the second thread to to read the data from the queue and write it to the SD card. As the queue could be accessed at the same time by but two (or possibly multiple) threads, we'd need a thread safe-queue like the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Apart from that, I think I *may* need to define my own code for the camera instead of just calling the camera activity as the default camera activity has a lag after capturing the photo. I may start a full-screen activity with just using the camera feed (for seeing where I am pointing at) and have a button which stores the current camera view (or take an image) when the button is clicked.